# How to write a document firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write a new document like this:

```
database.collection('NegociosDev').doc('Peluquerías').collection('Negocios').doc('PR01').collection('citas').add({
            CheckIn: formattedDate(citaDate) + ' ' + formattedTime(horaSelec),
            CheckOut: fechaFinal.toString(),
            Dirección: 'Avenida Los Majuelos 54',
            Negocio: 'PRIVILEGE SALONES',
            Precio: pre.toString(),
            Servicio: servicioSeleccionado.toString(),
            extraInformation: empleadoSelect.toString(),
            idUsuario: idUser.toString(),
        })
```

But I'm getting this error everytime I try to write anything (I can read it):

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Using this rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
    allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    allow read;
  }
 }
}
```

I'm not doing any authentication, I'm just trying to write some stuff, but I don't want to change the rules.

Answer (score 1):

You have to correctly set firestore rules.

I recommend you watch this official video [1] where they explain everything you need to know.

That video is part of the "Get to Know Cloud Firestore" playlist [2]. I really recommend you watch the whole playlist. Doesn't take too long, and it really pays off.

[1] https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw 
[2] https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not doing any authentication, I'm just trying to write some stuff, but I don't want to change the rules.

You won't be able to write if you don't authenticate (based on that rule)/

If you decide to remove the rile `allow write: if true`, be aware this is not secure, you can set it back after you are done with your tests.

Otherwise, you can authenticate your user, [documents are useful for this purpose](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/where-to-start)

Maybe check the local emulator, maybe it might help you, [docs are here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure)

Comment: Will check the docs, but there is no way (without changing the rules) to write, even if I'm an admin?

Comment: nope, there is no notion of "admin" (meaning the owner of he project), you could also try the local emulator, I will update my answer to provide you the docs for it but I haven't checked myself, probably you will need to change the rules but on your local environment which is ok, otherwise, no, there is no way to bypass the security rules because by design it's created to avoid exactly that.